# Как правильно задавать фильтр `ignore` при работе с shutil.copytree()

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, файловая-система, фильтрация

В [официальной документации](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shutil.html#copytree-example) показано как можно фильтровать файлы при копировании дерева по маске имени файла:

```
from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns
    
copytree(source, destination, ignore=ignore_patterns('*.pyc', 'tmp*'))
```

Как можно фильтровать файлы по другим атрибутам, например по дате создания/модификации, размеру и т.д.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно "подсмотреть" как реализована функция [shutil.ignore_patterns()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.ignore_patterns):

```
def ignore_patterns(*patterns):
    """Function that can be used as copytree() ignore parameter.

    Patterns is a sequence of glob-style patterns
    that are used to exclude files"""
    def _ignore_patterns(path, names):
        ignored_names = []
        for pattern in patterns:
            ignored_names.extend(fnmatch.filter(names, pattern))
        return set(ignored_names)
    return _ignore_patterns
```

и написать свою функцию, используя тот же принцип.

Например нам нужно скопировать все файлы (включая поддиректории), которые были созданы/модифицированы после определенного времени:

```
from shutil import copytree
from datetime import datetime as DT, timedelta
from pathlib import Path

def ignore_files(older_than):
    def _ignore(path, names):
        ignored_names = []
        for name in names:
            file_mtime = (Path(path) / name).stat().st_mtime
            if DT.fromtimestamp(file_mtime) < older_than:
                ignored_names.append(name)
        return set(ignored_names)
    return _ignore

DAYS = 7
older_than = DT.now() - timedelta(days=DAYS)

copytree(r'c:\incoming', r'c:\staging', ignore=ignore_files(older_than))
```